# Show that two $R$-algebras are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

> Consider the $\mathbb{R}$-algebras $A := \mathbb{R}\left[a,b,c,d\right]\left[\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}\right]$ and $B := \mathbb{R}\left[a,b,c,d\right]\left[\frac{1}{ad-bc}\right]$ (so we are adjoining the inverses of $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ and $ad-bc$, respectively).
> I claim that these are not isomorphic as $\mathbb{R}$-algebras, but I'm not sure how to formalize this.

My intuition says that this is because $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 0 \iff a=b=c=d=0,$$ while $ad-bc=0$ has nonzero solutions. I tried to formalize this using evaluation homomorphisms, but to no avail. I also tried assuming they were isomorphic and obtaining a contradiction, but haven't been able to.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proposition.** Let $R$ be a UFD and $p,q\in R$ prime elements. Let $\phi:R_p\to R_q$ be a ring isomorphism. Then $\phi(p)=uq$ or $\phi(p)=uq^{-1}$ with $u\in R$ invertible.
*Proof.* Since $p$ is invertible in $R_p$ its image by $\phi$ is also invertible, that is, $\phi(p)=uq^s$ with $u\in R$ invertible and $s\in\mathbb Z$. Conversely, $\phi^{-1}(q)=vp^t$ with $v\in R$ invertible and $t\in\mathbb Z$. Then $q=\phi(v)u^tq^{st}$ and since $q$ is prime we get $st=1$, so $s=\pm1$.

Now let $R=\mathbb R[a,b,c,d]$, $p=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ and $q=ad-bc$. Suppose that $\phi(p)=uq$ with $u\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Then $\phi(a)^2+\phi(b)^2+\phi(c)^2+\phi(d)^2=uq$. We can write $\phi(a)=a_1/q^i$ and so on. Then we get $a_1^2+b_1^2+c_1^2+d_1^2=uq^{2m+1}$ with $m$ a nonnegative integer. Now define a monomial order on $\mathbb R[a,b,c,d]$ such that $a>b>c>d$. Then the leading term of the right hand side is $(ad)^{2m+1}$, while the leading term of the left hand side is a sum at most four squares from $\mathbb R$ times the square of a monomial. Since that coefficient can not be zero (as it could happen if one works over $\mathbb C$, for instance!), we get a contradiction.

Comment: As you probably know the two rings are isomorphic if one replaces $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb C$, and I pointed out in my answer where exactly I have used that we work over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: could you please elaborate why you can write $\phi(a) = a_1/q^i$? Is $a_1$ a new variable? I didn't really understand this part

Comment: @dacian98 $a_1$ is a polynomial in $a,b,c,d$, and this is how one writes an element in $R_q$. (I didn't want to use too many letters, but if you like can write $\phi(a)=f/q^i$, $\phi(b)=g/q^j$, and so on.)

Comment: Aha, I understand! So $a_1, b_1$, etc. are polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[a,b,c,d]$. We suppose at least one of them contains a power of $ad$ (otherwise we are done). Then the leading term of the left hand side can only be $ad$ to an even power, because we are squaring each polynomial $a_1, b_1$, etc. Furthermore, the coefficient of the leading power of $ad$ on the LHS cannot be zero, because if it was, then we'd have that a sum of positive squares of real numbers is $0$, which is impossible. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: @dacian98 This is exactly how I've thought. (One more thing should be made clear in what you said: the leading monomial of a square of a polynomial is the square of its leading monomial.)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know a purely algebraic proof. The following proof involves a little algebraic geometry and algebraic topology, so it may not be the intended answer to your question. In that case, please specify your context (i.e. where did you get the problem from).

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as $\Bbb R$-algebras. Then their corresponding $\Bbb R$-points, viewed as real manifolds, are isomorphic, as polynomial maps are continuous (and even $C^\infty$).

However, these two manifolds are: $A(\Bbb R) = \Bbb R^4 \backslash \{0\}$ and $B(\Bbb R) = \operatorname{GL}(2, \Bbb R)$. It is obvious that they are not isomorphic as topological spaces, by e.g. comparing their simplicial (co)homology groups.

Comment: I am not very experienced in topology, but for the last part, could one argue that they are not isomorphic as topological spaces because $A(\mathbb{R})$ has one hole at the origin, whereas $B(\mathbb{R})$ has more than one hole (for example, at $(0,0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1,1)$)?

Comment: It's easier than that - $GL_2(\Bbb R)$ is disconnected (the components are things with positive determinant and things with negative determinant), while $\Bbb R^4\setminus 0$ is connected.

Answer (score -1):

**Question:** "Does anyone have any pointers on how to approach this?"

**Answer:** Your argument is correct: Define

$$A := \mathbb{R}[a,b,c,d]/(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2), B := \mathbb{R}[a,b,c,d]/(ad-bc).$$

Formally, if there is an isomorphism of affine schemes (over $k$ - the real numbers) $\phi: T:=Spec(A) \cong S:=Spec(B)$ it would follow that $T$ and $S$ have the same $k$-rational points: The map $\phi$ would induce a 1-1 correspondence

$$\phi(k): T(k) \cong S(k)$$

and an equality of sets

$$T(k) \cong Hom_{k-alg}(A,k) \cong Hom_{k-alg}(B,k)\cong S(k),$$

but $T$ has only one $k$-rational point: $x:=(0,0,0,0)$. $S$ has a rational point $x:=(a,b,c,d)$ for any $x$ with $det(x)=0$.

Formally: If $T\cong S$ are isomorphic schemes (over $k$) it follows $h_T\cong h_S$
are isomorphic as functors (over $k$). Hence an isomorphism $\phi$ of affine schemes over $k$ does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear with the question. When I wrote $A := \mathbb{R}[a,b,c,d][\frac{1}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}]$, I meant $\mathbb{R}[a,b,c,d]$ with the inverse of $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ adjoined to the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[a,b,c,d]$. So as a quotient ring, I guess this would look something like $A = \mathbb{R}[a,b,c,d,e]/\langle e(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2) - 1 \rangle$, where e plays the role of the inverse? Not entirely sure..